# Firebase: Run a query synchronously

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set some user data depending on the no.of users already in my USERS COLLECTION. This even includes a userId which should be a number.

```
exports.setUserData = functions.firestore.document('/users/{documentId}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users')
      .orderBy('userId', 'desc').limit(1)
      .get().then(function(snapshot) {

      const user = snapshot.docs[0].data();
      var lastUserId = user.userId;
          var userObject = {
            userId: lastUserId + 1,... some other fields here
          };

        event.data.ref.set(userObject, {
          merge: true
        });

      });
  });
```

One issue I noticed here, quickly adding 2 users result in those documents having the same `userId` may be because the `get()` query is asynchronous?

Is there a way to make this whole `setUserData` method synchronous?

Comment: you can use async/await, and your code becomes synchronous.

Comment: @amir Can you please point me to the related code

Comment: You can use `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to set value of `lastUserId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make Cloud Functions run your function invocations sequentially. That would also be quite contrary to the serverless promise of auto-scaling to demands.

But in your case there's a much simpler, lower level primitive to get a sequential ID. You should store the last known user ID in the database and then [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to read/update it.

```
var counterRef = admin.firestore().collection('counters').doc('userid');

return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(counterRef).then(function(counterDoc) {
        var newValue = (counterDoc.data() || 0) + 1;
        transaction.update(counterRef, newValue);
    });
});
```

**Solution**

```
var counterRef = admin.firestore().collection('counters').doc('userId');

return admin.firestore().runTransaction(function(transaction) {
  // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
  return transaction.get(counterRef).then(function(counterDoc) {
    var newValue = (counterDoc.data().value || 0) + 1;
    transaction.update(counterRef, {
      "value": newValue
    });
  });
}).then(t => {
  admin.firestore().runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(counterRef).then(function(counterDoc) {
      var userIdCounter = counterDoc.data().value || 0;

      var userObject = {
        userId: userIdCounter
      };

      event.data.ref.set(userObject, {
        merge: true
      });
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: and I can safely use `var userObject = {
            userId: newValue
          };

        event.data.ref.set(userObject, {
          merge: true
        });
` after `transaction.update(counterRef, newValue);` ??

Comment: Nope. As the comment (and the linked docs) says: that code may be run multiple times in case there are multiple clients updating the value at the same time. To ensure you have the actual committed value, attach a completion callback to the transaction:`runTransaction(...).then(...)`.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with a solution code. Can you please have a look.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted. If that's substantially different from my answer, post it as an answer (and upvote mine for being helpful). If it's not substantially different from what I wrote, accept my answer (and consider if it's worth providing your code improvements as an edit to my answer).